# Qsort dealing with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, qsort

I am having trouble with `qsort`, if someone can help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Also, I have searched SO plenty prior to asking, but no success.

Here's how my program is roughly set up:

~.h~

```
class playerClass{
    playerClass( ) { }
    ...
    double average;
};

class Stats{
    void update(...);
    ...
    playerClass *ar[1201];
};
```

~.cpp~

```
void update(...){
    playerClass *p = new playerClass( );
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        ...
        ar[j]->average = (ar[j]->hits)/(ar[j]->atBats);
        cout << "Average: " << ar[j]->average << endl;

        /* Prints Averages correctly, but I need everything to be sorted by
           the Averages, and I am instructed to use qsort */

        qsort(*ar, count, sizeof(playerClass*), compare);
        cout << "Sorted average: " << ar[j]->average << endl;
    }
}

int compare (const void *a, const void *b){
    playerClass *x = (playerClass*)a;
    playerClass *y = (playerClass*)b;

    /* I believe that I'm not correctly accessing the Averages with
       the two statements above, I have tried many different variations
       of them, but I am not actually able to access the averages correct.
       Can someone please help me, so that way I can get over this obstacle
       and continue this assignment? */

    if (x < y) return -1;
    if (x > y) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ have many nice [algorithms in its standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), ones that are better suited for C++ than the old C functions like `qsort`. I recommend you read about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Also note that `ar` is an array of pointers, which means that `*ar` will not do what you expect it to. I also recommend you read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - agree; but the "assignment" asked to use `qsort`...

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace these two lines in your `compare` function:

```
playerClass *x = (playerClass*)a;
playerClass *y = (playerClass*)b;
```

with

```
double x = ((playerClass*) a)->average;
double y = ((playerClass*) b)->average;
```

because you are using `x` and `y` to compare the averages, not to do the swapping. When you assign the pointer to the class to `x` and `y` you will compare their pointers - so your sort ends up "in the order in which they are placed in memory" - which is unlikely to be the order you wanted.

**update** here is a very simple program that creates a class, an array of elements of that class, and an array of pointers to the elements. It calls `qsort` using the array of pointers, and it demonstrates that the original array ends up sorted.

See if this helps you along...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class playerClass {
  public:
    double average;
};

// some values for initialization
double values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return (((playerClass*)a)->average - ((playerClass*)b)->average);
}

int main ()
{
  int ii;
  playerClass b[6];  // create 6 elements of the "class"
  playerClass *a[6]; // create pointers to the elements
  for(ii=0; ii<6; ii++) {
    b[ii].average = values[ii]; // put values in the elements
    a[ii] = &b[ii]; // make the pointers point to sensible things
  }

  qsort (a[0], 6, sizeof(playerClass), compare); // perform qsort
  // and print results:
  for (ii=0; ii<6; ii++)
     printf ("%.0f ",b[ii].average);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs the sorted values:

```
10 20 25 40 90 100
```

PS I apologize if this looks like C... it is, except for the `class` definition. I could have used `struct` with this kind of (functionless) class and it would have worked the same way.

PPS - you could have done

```
qsort(b, 6, sizeof(playerClass), compare);
```

and it would have worked equally well.

I think your problem is that you are still trying to sort something that is the size of a POINTER, when it should be the SIZE OF THE WHOLE CLASS OBJECT.

So I *think* that

```
qsort(ar, count, sizeof(playerClass), compare);
```

is the way to solve this (I just noticed that in one of your edits, you took out the line that said `playerClass *ar[N];`...)

**Side note**
It is difficult to follow answers if you edit the question to incorporate suggestions about errors. It is better to add an update below - something like

> "As @JohnDoe pointed out, I should have used `ar` instead of `*ar`. So I changed my code to `...` and now the problem is `...` For people who follow the question for a while and try to help you get to an answer, that is really helpful.

Otherwise we have to look at the edit history to figure out what has been happening. Make sense?

Comment: Hi Floris, that does make sense to me, I appreciate it. I took your advice, but my program seg faulted, which I fixed by making the first parameter of the qsort from *ar to simply ar. At least, it compiles now and is different from the unsorted average, but it's still not sorted in an ascending or descending order. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to use `qsort` at all? Try it with a simple array of doubles and make sure you can get that to work before something complex like this. I often find that going in small steps gets you to the answer. Array of doubles -> array of structs -> class array would be the way I would slowly make my problem harder; then when it breaks I have a way to narrow it down.

Comment: If the above is not enough, it would be helpful if you would show a little bit more code - for example, how values in `ar` are initialized, and how you print out their "sorted" values. In other words - a more complete program. Very often "the problem is in the code you didn't show". This is beginning to smell like that...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Floris answer, you should move `qsort` outside the loop. Otherwise you sort the array multiple times unnecessarily.

You must also give the address of `ar`, not the first element

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ...
}

qsort(ar, count, sizeof(ar[0]), compare);
```

Also note, that `compare` must be a free function or a static member of some class.

*Update:*

I copied the call to `qsort` without paying attention to the `sizeof` part. `qsort` needs the size of the array's elements, which is a *pointer* to `playerClass`. You can either give the first element `ar[0]`

```
qsort(ar, count, sizeof(ar[0]), compare);
```

or the correct type `playerClass*`

```
qsort(ar, count, sizeof(playerClass*), compare);
```

*Update:*

Third try, you want to sort an array of pointers. This has two implications

- As noted above you must give `sizeof(playerClass*)` for the size argument to qsort
- The arguments to the comparison functions are pointers to the elements, in this case pointers to pointers to `playerClass`. This results in the following comparison function

  ```
  int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
  {
      playerClass *x = *(playerClass**)a;
      playerClass *y = *(playerClass**)b;

      if (x->average < y->average)
          return -1;

      if (x->average > y->average)
          return 1;

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: yes - I had only focused on the "I am accessing the averages wrong" part of the question but you are absolutely right about this.